# Nextjs виджет шаринга в Telegram

Tags: nextjs

Приложение Nextjs, App Router. Необходимо было реализовать кнопку шаринга динамической страницы в Телеграм. Кнопка работает, шаринг тоже, но в Телеграм сообщение оформляется не виджетом, а просто ссылка и подпись.

Разметка на месте:

```
   <meta property="og:title" content="Какой-то контент"/>
   <meta property="og:description" content="Какой-то контент"/>
   <meta property="og:image" content="https://<link here>"/>
   <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
```

С других, статичных роутов все ок, есть виджет в телеге. А с динамической страницы нет.

Плиз, хелп.